# If both $f$ and $\hat{f}$ are in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, then they are both in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: normed-spaces, fourier-transform

I want to prove this statement, and my very naive idea is to use Schwarz inequality in some way. However it seems $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{L^2}$ is likely on the RHS of $\leq$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$\lVert \hat{f} \rVert_{L^2}\leqslant
\lVert  \hat{f} \rVert_{L^1}^{\frac{1}{2}}
\lVert  \hat{f} \rVert_{L^\infty}^{\frac{1}{2}}\leqslant
\lVert  \hat{f} \rVert_{L^1}^{\frac{1}{2}}
\lVert  f \rVert_{L^1}^{\frac{1}{2}},$$
we have $\hat{f}\in L^2(\mathbb{R}).$

A similar proof gives $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}).$

Comment: Is it Hölder's inequality for the first $\leq$?

Comment: Observe $\int |\hat f|^2 \leq \|\hat f\|_\infty \int |\hat f|$

Comment: @Jacky Chong Thank you